# System.Windows.Interactivity for .NET 4.5 wpf project for .NET 4.5 wpf project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nuget, mahapps.metro

Recently i have migrated my WPF project from .NET4.0 to .NET 4.5 and i am facing 
System.Windows.Interactivity issue which was otherwise working fine.

> Error :  Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Have you tried removing the assembly and re-adding it to the proect? Also, if you have more than one assembly loaded in your project make sure they all use the same version of System.Windows.Interactivity.

Comment: I have never used that package (UPDATE: The OP deleted the comment I was referring to). I use the one that ships with visual studio in the normal "Add reference" window when I use the Interactivity dll.

Comment: I tried to use this https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/  and after that I am able to see entry in my package.config as 
  <package id="System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF" version="2.0.20525" targetFramework="net45" />   looks like this issue is resolved but i am not sure as my app is still not up and getting issue related to mah.app   {"The type initializer for 'MahApps.Metro.Behaviours.StylizedBehaviors' threw an exception."}    i am using <package id="MahApps.Metro" version="1.2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />  It may be a different issue but any help appriciated.