# mahapp Lost window style after updated to latest version

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I recently Moved to the latest version of MahApp available on NUget.I changed because i moved my application .Net4.0 to .NET 4.5.
[System.Windows.Interactivity for .NET 4.5 wpf project for .NET 4.5 wpf project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929394/system-windows-interactivity-for-net-4-5-wpf-project-for-net-4-5-wpf-project)
After this i am facing issues with Window style Please find the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Where do you add the MahApps resources?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the same by creating a WPF application in Net40 framework and following the MahApps document to add the library and styles. Then I migrated the project to Net45. After I removed the

1. Package.config file
2. MahApps.Metro reference from the project
3. System.Windows.Interactivity reference from the project

Then again install the MahApps libraries by

> Install-Package MahApps.Metro

in package manager console. And when I run i the same application it just works fine. This is my App.Xaml code as per the docs

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

But what I observed is when i remove this line

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
```

I am getting the same style as you described in the image

[image]

If I add that line then everything works fine,

[image]

So I guess you App.Xaml should miss something.

I apologize if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks shasfk!! It worked for me. I did +1 but it will take time to show. Since my reputation is too low :(.

Comment: How about if I just want it to apply on Window only not on other controls? if i include it in my resuorceDictionary my other controls styles getting screwed up. From MahApp I am only using Window nothing else.

Comment: Ok. I got your question. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Hi Shansfk!! Hope i will get the tricky bit to update only specific control(Window) and not to impact other control of my application from this resource.